# Visual Studio Explorer missing folder structure when opening folder using "Open with Code" option from File Explorer

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, directory, explorer

I am able to right click the folder and 'open with code' in File Explorer. It is opening Visual Studio Code, but the folder structure/files are not visible in the explorer

[image: open with code showing while opening the folder]

[image: folder not visible in the vs code explorer]

I tried to open a folder in Visual Studio Code by right clicking and selecting the open with code option. I am expecting the folder and its structure/files to be visible in the Visual Studio Code explorer.

Comment: You could try this command to see if by chance it helps: `View: Reset View Locations`.

Comment: either you haven't enabled the "Folders" subview, or you moved that subview elsewhere. To enable it, click the three dot menu at the top of the Explorer View and check "Folders". If it doesn't appear, do the thing Mark suggested.

Comment: It's solved with the thing Mark said. Thanks!